# Buttons on HTML Page not working in Safari / on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have some Bootstrap-based HTML pages with some javascript and internal CSS, served in Flask, using Jinjja templates. It works perfectly fine on Windows and Android, using Chrome. But when I try to click certain buttons while on an iPhone (Chrome) or on Safari, they don't work. There's no error message in Chrome either.

Here's a sample of the button I used:

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <form action="/skill" method="get">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical mt-10" style="width:100%">
      <button  id="Health" onClick="selection(this.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" style="background-color: #4a8bae;white-space: normal;">
        <h4 class="display-5 pt-2">Health</h4>
        <p class="mb-2 font-weight-normal">The centre of human happiness and well-being.</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

After clicking the button, it's supposed to sessionstorage the id chosen.

Please advise on what I can do to fix this! Let me know if I should post any other information. Thank you!

Comment: maybe iPhone (Chrome) or on Safari dislike h4 and p wrapped button, try to change it for div with same attributes plus role="button" or change button to submit and work with form event onsubmit

Comment: Could you explain what 'don't work' means? If I replace the onclick function with an alert it works fine on IOS Safari, i.e. it isn't objecting to having H4 and P tags inside a button (though you should not do this as @DaniilLoban has said). Perhaps you could make a snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: @DaniilLoban I tried it and it works on some pages! :) On others, I need to use buttons for some javascript code to work, so i still need other solutions if possible

Comment: @AHaworth I made this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/tfortammi/rusx18tf
The title should change to the name of the button clicked and the next button should lead to a 404 if the page works. 

I followed DaniilLoban 's suggestion and it worked, but I have another page that necessitates buttons so it would be good to figure out why it's not working. I'll prepare another snippet of the other page soon!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, but at least in my case I just turned of the safari's pop-up blocker (at the iphone settings) and everything works fine...